# Very Simple K-means clustering example in ELKI

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, elki

I'm currently trying to use the KMeans Clustering functionality provided by the elki library.

This is what I came up with:

```
    double[][] dblArray = new double[100][10]  // 100 10-dimensional data points

    //populate array...        

    KMeansInitialization<NumberVector<Double>> kinit = new FirstKInitialMeans<>();

    KMeansLloyd<NumberVector<Double>, DoubleDistance> kmeans 
        = new KMeansLloyd<NumberVector<Double>, DoubleDistance>(EuclideanDistanceFunction.STATIC, K, KMEANSMAXITER, kinit);

    DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(dblArray));
    Database d = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc, null);

    kmeans.run(d);
```

Elki gives me:

> de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.type.NoSupportedDataTypeException: No data
>   type found satisfying: NumberVector,field AND NumberVector Available
>   types:    at
>   de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.AbstractDatabase.getRelation(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.AbstractAlgorithm.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to initialize your database:

```
d.initialize();
```

at this point, data will be fetched from the database connections, and indexes will be built.

If you forget to initialize your database, it will remain empty.